# Splitting a `Vec`

Tags: rust, unsafe, borrow-checker

I'm trying to write a little buffer-thing for parsing so I can pull records off the front of as I parse them out, ideally without making any copies and just transferring ownership of chunks of the front of the buffer off as I run. Here's my implementation:

```
struct BufferThing {
    buf: Vec<u8>,
}

impl BufferThing {
    fn extract(&mut self, size: usize) -> Vec<u8> {
        assert!(size <= self.buf.len());
        let remaining: usize = self.buf.len() - size;
        let ptr: *mut u8 = self.buf.as_mut_ptr();

        unsafe {
            self.buf = Vec::from_raw_parts(ptr.offset(size as isize), remaining, remaining);
            Vec::from_raw_parts(ptr, size, size)
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles, but panics with a `signal: 11, SIGSEGV: invalid memory reference` as it starts running. This is mostly the same code as the example in [the Nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/borrow-splitting.html), but I'm trying to do it on `Vec`'s and I'm trying to split a field instead of the object itself.

Is it possible to do this without copying out one of the `Vec`s? And is there some section of the Nomicon or other documentation that explains why I'm blowing everything up in the `unsafe` block?

Comment: It is a *very bad idea* to use `unsafe` code if you cannot explain why it is indeed safe.

Comment: You could maybe achieve what you want using splices. split vector into two slices for example elements [0,1,2] and [3...] and you then process 0,1,2. and then in next iteration take [0.1.2] from that 2nd splice.  Also VecDeque comes to mind.

Comment: Does your parser really consume a Vec? I would imagine your parser would be happy with a slice.

Comment: The buffer's being read from a very large file so I can't fit it all in memory at once (and the buffer changes as I read the file so I have lifetime issues with slices). Copying is an okay solution, but I was looking to see if there was something a bit more clever I could do to prevent that.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, that's not how memory allocators work. It might have been possible in the past, when memory was at a premium, but today's allocators are geared for speed rather than memory preservation.

A common implementation of memory allocators is to use slabs. Basically, it's:

```
struct Allocator {
    less_than_32_bytes: List<[u8; 32]>,
    less_than_64_bytes: List<[u8; 64]>,
    less_than_128_bytes: List<[u8; 128]>,
    less_than_256_bytes: List<[u8; 256]>,
    less_than_512_bytes: List<[u8; 512]>,
    ...
}
```

When you request 96 bytes, it takes an element from `less_than_128_bytes`.

When you free that element, it frees *all* of it, not just the first N bytes, and the whole block is now re-usable. Any pointer inside the block is now dangling and should NOT be dereferenced.

Furthermore, trying to free a pointer in the middle of a block will only confuse the allocator: it won't find it, because the contract is that you address blocks by their first byte.

You violated the contract using `unsafe` code, *BOOM*.

---

The solution I propose is simple:

- use a single `Vec<u8>` containing the *whole* buffer to parse
- use slices into this `Vec` for parsing

Rust will check the lifetimes, so your slices cannot outlive the buffer, and slicing a slice further (`s[..offset]`, `s[offset..]`) does not allocate.

---

If you don't mind *one* allocation, there's [`Vec::split_off`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.split_off) which allocates a new `Vec` big enough for the split part.

Comment: @Shepmaster: it allocates, I don't like allocations :)

Comment: @Shepmaster: Well, the OP asked without allocations ;) We can either edit the title to reflect it or I can edit my answer to include `Vec::split_off` as an allocating alternative. I'm not sure what's the best, what do you think?

Comment: @Shepmaster: I was looking at *Is it possible to do this without copying out one of the Vecs?*; I can modify my answer for now, seems easier.